# OIM Custom ICF based connector throwing runtime exception

Tags: java, identity-management, oim

I have created one ICF based Flat file connector which uses REST web service to Read/write the data from file. I have used **jersey implementation 1.6** to write the web service and the java client which will call that web service.

I am using stand alone java code for testing the **CRUD** functionality.It's giving exception at first line where I am initializing the jersey Client.

```
Client flatFileRestClient = Client.create();
```

I got to know that the error is because the connector server is not able to recognize the jersey implementation jars.So as per documentation of ICF connector i had put the jersey bundle jar in **connector server/lib** folder. I had restarted the connector server and invoke create operation but issue still exists.

I had also added the class path of custom jar in **ConnectorServer.bat**
file located in **CONNECTOR_SERVER_HOME/bin**. Still the issue persists.

Please find full stack trace of the exception thrown on eclipse console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.serializer.CommonObjectHandlers$17.createException(CommonObjectHandlers.java:301)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.serializer.CommonObjectHandlers$ThrowableHandler.deserialize(CommonObjectHandlers.java:115)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.serializer.binary.BinaryObjectDecoder$InternalDecoder.readObject(BinaryObjectDecoder.java:162)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.serializer.binary.BinaryObjectDecoder.readObject(BinaryObjectDecoder.java:313)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.serializer.binary.BinaryObjectDecoder.readObjectField(BinaryObjectDecoder.java:417)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.serializer.MessageHandlers$5.deserialize(MessageHandlers.java:155)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.serializer.binary.BinaryObjectDecoder$InternalDecoder.readObject(BinaryObjectDecoder.java:162)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.serializer.binary.BinaryObjectDecoder.readObject(BinaryObjectDecoder.java:313)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.remote.RemoteFrameworkConnection.readObject(RemoteFrameworkConnection.java:153)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.remote.RemoteOperationInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteOperationInvocationHandler.java:101)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.create(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.DelegatingTimeoutProxy.invoke(DelegatingTimeoutProxy.java:107)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.create(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.LoggingProxy.invoke(LoggingProxy.java:76)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.create(Unknown Source)
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.AbstractConnectorFacade.create(AbstractConnectorFacade.java:123)
at org.identityconnectors.flatfileconnector.test.TestOperations.create(TestOperations.java:37)
at org.identityconnectors.flatfileconnector.test.TestOperations.main(TestOperations.java:44)
```

Please below exceptions thrown on connector server:

```
Jun 06, 2016 5:19:13 PM org.identityconnectors.framework.server.impl.ConnectionL
istener processOperationRequest
SEVERE: javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers
        at org.identityconnectors.flatfileconnector.restclient.FlatFileRestClient.<
init>(FlatFileRestClient.java:18)
        at org.identityconnectors.flatfileconnector.FlatFileConnector.create(FlatFileConnector.java:85)
        at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.CreateImpl
.create(CreateImpl.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ConnectorA
PIOperationRunnerProxy.invoke(ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.create(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ThreadClas
sLoaderManagerProxy.invoke(ThreadClassLoaderManagerProxy.java:107)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.create(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.DelegatingTimeoutProxy.invo
ke(DelegatingTimeoutProxy.java:107)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.create(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.LoggingProxy.invoke(Logging
Proxy.java:76)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.create(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.identityconnectors.framework.server.impl.ConnectionProcessor.proc
essOperationRequest(ConnectionProcessor.java:287)
        at org.identityconnectors.framework.server.impl.ConnectionProcessor.proc
essRequest(ConnectionProcessor.java:191)
        at org.identityconnectors.framework.server.impl.ConnectionProcessor.run(
ConnectionProcessor.java:121)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 37 more
```

Any help at the earliest would appreciate.

Comment: can you try the client code without connector server? and let me know the results?

Comment: Thanks Chaitanya                                                                                        Yes the custom Java client is working fine. It's reading/writing the date from/to file.

Comment: I have not crated the OIM metadata for the connector. Right now i am building the connector code only.

Comment: Does that mean your query is resolved ? or you need to try it once you are done with the Metadata thing?

Comment: I see the issue is more with the jersey jars as the error thrown on connector server was classNotFound. I would trying that bce OIM metadata is ready. But wanted to know why that is not working standalone java code.

Comment: It should work standalone too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the REST API jars which i was using. I have de-compile the **jersey-bundle-1.6.jar** and found the `javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers.class` is not present in that jar. So i have downloaded the Java 6 complied version of the [Jersey-bundler-1.16.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjerseybundle116jar.htm)